# Drop down menu for column visualization in Holoviews

Tags: python, holoviews

I have a dataframe with time index and some columns, similar to

```
dt, col1, col2, col3
12, 0.9, 0.3, 0.1
13, 0.9, 0.3, 0.2
14, 2.9, 0.4, 0.1
15, 0.1, 0.3, 0.7
```

and I can create a Holoviews Curve wihtout a problem for each column. Is it possible to generate a graph with a drop down menu selecting between [col1, col2, col3]?

Answer (score 1):

HoloViews is primarily set up to plot so called "tidy" or long dataframes easily, so to take full advantage of the power of HoloViews you will want to convert the data to that format. The `pd.melt` function is very useful to convert "wide" to tidy data. Based on your example you could do something like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dt': range(10), 'col1': np.random.rand(10),
                   'col2': np.random.rand(10), 'col3': np.random.rand(10)})
tidy_df = pd.melt(df, id_vars='dt', var_name='column', value_name='value')
ds = hv.Dataset(tidy_df)
ds.to(hv.Curve, 'dt', 'value', 'column')
```

Alternatively you can also manually create a HoloMap manually:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dt': range(10), 'col1': np.random.rand(10),
               'col2': np.random.rand(10), 'col3': np.random.rand(10)})
hv.HoloMap({col: hv.Curve(df, 'dt', col) for col in ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']},
           kdims='Column')
```

Having said all this, your use case is a very common one and the next release of HoloViews will include ways of making this kind of thing much easier, so look out for a user guide about working with pandas DataFrames once that lands.

Comment: Thanks, philippjfr! One thing that I noticed is that if the dataframe is in tidy format but the variable is in different scales, the Curve graph uses the largest scale, so the graphs are not that useful.

Comment: You can add ``%%opts Curve {+framewise}`` to the top of the cell to make it adjust the range when you select the dropdown value.